# How to implement NSCoding

Tags: swift, nscoding

```
import Foundation

class C: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var n: String = ""

    override init() {
        super.init()
        n = "instance of class C"
    }

    convenience init(_ name: String) {
        self.init()
        n = name
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        // self.init()
        // super.init()
        // super.init(coder)
        n = coder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as String
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encodeObject(n, forKey:"name")
    }

    override var description: String {
        get { return "C instance: \(n)" }
    }
}

let c = C("Tom")
println(c)
if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(c, toFile: "demo") {
    println("OK")
}
let c2: C = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile("demo") as C
```

Compiled on the command line with

```
xcrun swift coder.swift
```

The call `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile` fails, crashing with this

```
> xcrun swift coder.swift
C instance: Tom
OK
2014-09-06 10:45:11.925 swift[483:100b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (coder.C)'
```

I've looked at various "working examples" but they don't seem to work for me.  None of the commented lines work or help.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend opening a radar (bugreport.apple.com). This works fine if you compile it rather than trying to run it directly via the `swift` interpretter. It works in Xcode. It works in playgrounds. It works with `xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc coder.swift && ./coder`. The only case where it does not work is via `swift`.

Comment: Thanks.  Works for me now too.  I'll look into how to file a radar.